# Determining isometry group of symmetric spaces

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, symmetry

I am learning some symmetric spaces, and I tried to look at some example, including Grassmannian (say, $p$-dimensional subspaces in $\mathbb{C}^{p+q}$) and the projective space $\mathbb{CP}^n$. I follow Helgason, therefore I wish to describe them in terms of Lie groups. My problem is:

How to determine the isometry group of a manifold whose geometric description is known?

Let me elaborate more. For $\mathbb{CP}^n$, I understand that the special unitary group $SU(n+1)$ acts transitively on it. Also, I know the isotropy group for a certain point is $U(n)$. It is tempting now to claim $\mathbb{CP}^n = SU(n+1)/U(n)$. But I have not checked that $SU(n+1)$ *is* the isometry group!

Similar problems arise when I try Grassmannians, Lagrangian Grassmannians, Orthogonal Grassmannians, etc. I usually can find a group acting well on these spaces but I cannot determine whether that group is the isometry group.

Anyone can help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do you care about isometries? What structure do your spaces have? Do they have metrics at all?

Comment: @AmitaiYuval Aha, yes, they do. Let me illustrate with the projective space. It naturally carries the Fubini-Study metric which turns it into a Hermitian (and hence Riemannian, of course) symmetric space. We can even describe the involutive isometries explicitly using homogeneous coordinates. Similar metrics can be given to the Grassmannians.

Answer (score 1):

It usually goes the other way around.

Take the real Grassmannian space $Gr_k(n)$ for example. The group $O(n)$ acts on it transitively by diffeomorphisms, and the isotropy group is $O(k)\times O(n-k)$. This indeed shows that $$Gr_k(n)=O(n)/(O(k)\times O(n-k)),$$as a *diffeomorphism of smooth manifolds*. Then, it is natural to equip $Gr_k(n)$ with the unique Riemannian metric which makes the quotient map $O(n)\to Gr_k(n)$ a Riemannian submersion.

The same reasoning applies for all the other examples. If you deal with complex and Hermitian structures, just make sure that the group acts by biholomorphisms.

It is true that, if your symmetric space already has a metric, you need to verify that the group acts on it by isometries. This may be the case with $\mathbb{C}P^n$, as the Fubini-Study metric can be constructed by a few different approaches.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! There are a few points I'm not too sure about. First, I can realize the Grassmannian as a submanifold of a big projective space, via the so called Plucker embedding. Thus I am specifying a metric on Gr, which is induced from the Fubini-Study metric of the ambient projective space, and I would like to find the isometry group with respect to this particular metric. Secondly, not only O(n) but SO(n) also acts transitively on Gr, and that is exactly where my question arise: How can I know there is not a larger group of isometries than O(n) that acts transitively?

Comment: @WuYaochen Does it bother you so much if there is a bigger isometry group? There may be more than one way to represent a space as a quotient of a group.